# How to make a chinese doggy bag?

Tags: modeling, objects

[image]

Hello, 
I'm new with this program and I really need your help!!
I'd like to make a doggy bag like this image, without food.
I could find some tutorials making box but I would like to make the bottom round and the top opening part in square.
Is there sweet somebody who can explain me this easily please??
That would be so lovely!
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do it this way:

- Create a plane and subdivide it twice.
- Bring the additional edge loops close to the borders.
- Extrude down the whole plane and recalculate the normals with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.
- Remove the bottom, select the rim and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > *Circle* to make your square a circle (if you don't see the *LoopTools* you need to activate the addon in the *Preferences*).
- Now your bottom is a circle, rotate it on the Z axis so that it's correctly aligned.
- If you give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier you'll have a smooth object but your top angles won't be sharp anymore. To sharp then back create some additional edge loops with some <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>.
- Remove the top faces.
- Close the bottom with some extrudes, then a merge: <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> > *At Center*.
- You can add a *Solidify* modifier to give it thickness.

[image]